# Python Renaming Multiple Files in Directory

Tags: python, rename

Beginner question: I am trying to rename all .xlsx files within a directory. I understand how to replace a character in string with another, but how about removing? More specifically, I have multiple files in a directory: 0123_TEST_01, 0456_TEST_02. etc. I am trying to remove the prefix in the file name, which would result in the following: TEST_01, TEST_02.

I am attempting to use os.rename and throw it into a loop, but am unsure if I should use len() and some math to try and return the correct naming convention. The below code is where I currently stand. Please let me know if this does not make sense. Thanks.

```
import os
import shutil
import glob

src_files = os.listdir('C:/Users/acars/Desktop/b')

for file_name in src_files: 
       os.rename(fileName, filename.replace())
```

Comment: use `.find()` to find the location of `_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split once on an underscore and use the second element, glob will also find all your `xlsx` file for you are return the *full path*:

```
from os import path, rename
from glob import glob

src_files = glob('C:/Users/acars/Desktop/b/*.xlsx')
pth = 'C:/Users/acars/Desktop/b/'

for file_name in src_files:         
    rename(file_name, path.join(pth, path.basename(file_name).split("_",1)[1])
```

If you only have xlsx files and you did not use glob you would need to join the paths:

```
from os import path, rename
from glob import glob


pth = 'C:/Users/acars/Desktop/b'
src_files = os.listdir(pth)

for file_name in src_files:
    new = file_name.split("_", 1)[1]
    file_name = path.join(pth, file_name)
    rename(file_name, path.join(pth, new))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am attempted this method, which seems to be getting me closer, but am still seeing some issues. I attempted 'from os import path, name' which told me os was not defined. So I just imported all of os. The program ran without error, but seems to have moved the files because they are no longer in the directory. Then, when I recreate the docs and rerun, it says it cannot create a file because it already exists. It's as if it is working, I just can't see the renamed files in the B directory. All the help is appreciated!

Comment: @AndrewC10, I should have use rename not os.rename as I imported rename from os.  If you are getting an OsError because the file exists then it must have been successful.  when you run the code what does `print path.join(pth, new)`  output?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should've clarified. I used your top version of the code. I did import glob. It is telling me file_name is not defined. Below is what I ran. I tried defining path down to the file level and stopping at the directory level.                                                                                     pth = 'C:/Users/acars/Desktop/b/*.xlsx'
new = file_name.split("_", 1)[1]
print path.join(pth, new)

Comment: @AndrewC10, run it exactly as I have it in my answer now

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks a ton! I'm going to dig through what you did, but it looks like a combination of joining the path and applying the split.

Comment: we just pull the basename of the file and split that so we remove the substring up to the up to and including the first underscore, we just join that to the initial path, we don't need to join the file_name for the rename  as glob gives you the full path

Comment: Noted. Thank you again for the help. This is one piece of an automated software testing project.

Comment: no worries, both methods will work but with glob you don't have to do any filtering of the files.

Answer (score 1):

Just split the file name by underscore, ignore the first part, and join it back again.

```
>>> file_name = '0123_TEST_01'

>>> '_'.join(file_name.split('_')[1:])
'TEST_01'
```

Your code will look like this:

```
for file_name in src_files:
     os.rename(file_name, '_'.join(file_name.split('_')[1:]))
```

Comment: It's throwing up     os.rename(file_name, "_".join(file_name.split("_")[1:]))
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified. Is my src_files location to high up since it is try access the files within the b folder?

Comment: @Andrec10 that is because you have to give the absolute path to the file a os.rename, save in a variable, `path` for exmple, the folder you are working on, and do  `os.rename( os.path.join(path,file_name), os.path.join(path, '_'.join(file_name.split('_')[1:])) `